# Можете объяснить этот Pl/SQL код

Tags: sql, plsql

Здесь два раза объявляется переменные. Вот этого не могу понять.До IS и после IS объявляется.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function FindCourse
   ( name_in IN varchar2 )
   RETURN number
IS
   cnumber number;
```

Comment: name_in IN varchar2 - входящая переменная в функцию FindCourse.  RETURN number - тип возвращаемых данных.  cnumber number локальная переменная функции

Comment: Тела функции не хватает

Comment: Вопрос к "местным". Мой комментарий оформлять в качестве ответа. Или вопрос не совсем соответствует тематике сайта?

Comment: А что тут делает тег "mysql"? он-то как раз от такой конструкции прибалдеет...

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function FindCourse
   ( name_in IN varchar2 )  /* входящая переменная в функцию FindCourse*/
   RETURN number /* тип возвращаемых данных*/
IS
   cnumber number; /* локальная переменная функции*/
```